# How to link a relative html file in the scenario where user can call the files from the browser by adding a / at the end

Tags: html, hyperlink, relative-path

(Sorry I am not able to frame question correctly.)

Following is the scenario.

I have 2 Html files.

File1.Html has

```
<a href="File2.html">Click Me</a>
```

File2.Html has

```
<a href="File1.html">Click Me</a>
```

Now when I open the file1.html in browser by typing following in browser.

```
http://Localhost/File1.html
```

The file1.html with a link is shown and when clicked it goes to

```
http://Localhost/File2.html
```

BUT

If I open the file1.html in browser by typing following in browser(note  the / at the end).

```
http://Localhost/File1.html/
```

The file1.html with a link is shown and when clicked it goes to

```
http://Localhost/File1.html/File2.html
```

I know this is not a right way to do in browser but you cant stop user doing so.

The above example I have used just to simplify the issue. My real production issue issue is while using the MVC url are actually routed. So a user can legally use http://example.com/Employee Or http://example.com/Employee/ and due to this my jqGrid is not working.

Please guide me for a workaround.

UPDATE:
This works ok in IExplorer : wierd.

Comment: Don't forget the web server's role in all this. The web server must recognise these 'weird' URLs and still serve the pages you request.

Comment: @pavium Try the same with file://file1.html you will get the same result so webserver is not involved here.

Comment: No, as you said, you can't stop users typing in strange URLs but I wondered if something could be done by configuring the web server, or getting help from the web server (if there is one)

Answer (score 2):

You want a link relative to the **root**. The following:

```
<a href="/File1.html">Click Me</a>
```

(note the '/' at the start of the href) will link to http://Localhost/File1.html wherever the page containing the link is (so long as it's on the same host).

Comment: That’s called an absolute URL path.

Comment: It's rooted, but not absolute as usually understood by that term (eg. RFC 2396)

Comment: you can use .. to ascend a directory, (e.g. <a href="../File1.html">Click Me</a>). Otherwise you cannot do this with plain HTML. Consider using a framework or design that allows you to give absolute paths in all cases.

Comment: @bobince: I think you rather mean an *absolute URL* but not *absolute URL path*.

Answer (score 0):

> not relative to root i need it relative to parent

That's not possible. If you are using routed URIs there can be all sorts of /path/segments following the base name. The browser has no way of knowing what the real ‘parent’ is.

The usual solution is to use root-relative URIs as suggested by Joe. If you need to allow your application to be mounted at a configurable prefix under the root, that prefix will need to be copied out into the link.

Answer (score 0):

Your question reminds me of a technique for search friendly URLs, implemented in PHP.

Things like:

```
http://localhost/index.php/2009/09/
```

It was described [on Sitepoint.com](http://www.sitepoint.com/article/search-engine-friendly-urls/) The idea was that index.php could retrieve the trailing part of the URL from the web server and decide what to do with it. Including whether to deal with a final / or not.

**It won't be relevant to html files** (which could not, after all, retrieve the trailing part of a URL) but it might provide further ideas.